# Using a session variable in the where clause of a LINQ statement

Tags: linq, gridview, datasource

Good afternoon all.

I have a page that displays data in a gridview based upon what the user selects for a material in a radiobutton list and how many they wish to see, a text box.

Upon logging into this page, a session variable for MemberID is created, MemberKey.

What I would like to do is pass this session variable into the LINQ statement so that only the specific member that has logged in sees their data:

```
        ContextTypeName="VDSWeightsReportingService.CompleteWeightsDataContext" EnableInsert="True" 
            EnableUpdate="True" TableName="tblOnlineReportingCOMPLETEWEIGHTSFINALDEMOs" 

        Where="MaterialText == @MaterialText &amp;&amp; Productpriority &lt;= @Productpriority &amp;&amp; MemberId == @MemberId">
            <WhereParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="radMaterial" Name="MaterialText" 
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="tbxHowMany" Name="Productpriority" 
                    PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
               <asp:SessionParameter Name="MemberId" SessionField="MemberKey" 
                    Type="String" />
            </WhereParameters>
        </asp:LinqDataSource>
```

I have tried to insert the session variable as above but without the LINQ no longer seems to go through the motions.

Can someone point out to me where I am going wrong?

If this doesn't work, or is not possible, can someone advise of a way around this? i.e. using this session variable in the LINQ where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you select the correct session variable!!!!